# Как отправить сообщение в whatsapp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, whatsapp

Я хочу отправить сообщение в `whatsapp`, используя `python`, без сторонних сервисов по типу `twilio` или `chat api`...

Могу я реализовать это, используя **post**-запрос?

Comment: Нашёл способ как реализовать отправку запросом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется вы сможете реализовать отправку.

Только перед этим вам необходимо пройти авторизацию:

1. Первым делом получить Token и QR изображение (по сути вы будете эмулировать работу webwhatsapp).
2. Затем с мобильного устройства сканируете этот код и получаете callback от системы whatsapp об успешной авторизации и собственно Token.
3. Дальше уже вы сможете отправлять сообщения простым Post запросом.

Сторонние сервисы выполняют ту же работу, только за вас.

Просто отправить сообщение, не пройдя авторизацию не получится.

P.S. Многие данные придется брать из JavaScript, т.к. отловив просто запросы, много информации не получите, что усложняет процесс эмуляции.